# What should I do when main display shows slim horizontal lines on a Macbook pro 2017 touchbar model?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hardware, gpu

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) with touch bar

Radeon Pro 555 2GB
Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB**

I have horizontal lines all over my macbook screen. The first time this problem occurred was when I unplugged my macbook from the monitor (when the macbook was connected to the monitor it was closed, the image was only displayed on the monitor), then when I opened it again these lines appeared. When I connect the macbook to the monitor, the image is displayed as it should be. what should I do?

Edit:
Now I see that it also leaves a trace of the recently opened windows

I discoverd one more strange thing , when I close my laptop and it is somewhere less than 45 degrees, the stripes disappear, what can you mean

Comment: Based n your edit, you might have a flex cable issue. It still could  be the GPU, but either way, it’s a physical issue and needs to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Good thinking with the external monitor. Next is to boot to recovery. When you are running the recovery OS that will also test if the issue is hardware related or OS install related.

If it’s the os, backup and erase and restore.

- https://support.apple.com/mac-backup

If it’s the hardware, then seeking service is next. (Do the backup and prepare for service steps from the link above)

- https://locate.apple.com

Comment: i have update to download do you think it can help its macos Montrey